# How can I replace price with text?

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I have a Squarespace site created last year, where I am using the commerce functions to have a "webshop" where I can show used products I have for sale. Some products are difficult to set a price for, so I want to have the price say "price on request" if the price is set to 0 in the inventory management. Ever since the creation, I have had the following custom code injection to automatically change prices that are 0 to "Price on request". For some reason this has now stopped working. I'm not sure exactly when.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-price'), sf, len = products.length;
  for (sf=0; sf<len; sf++) {
    var price = products[sf].querySelector('.sqs-money-native');
    if (price.textContent === '0.00') {
      price.parentNode.textContent = 'Price on request';  
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Any thoughts on why this suddenly doesn't work?

Comment: Please revise to add some representative HTML. See [ask]. You can put it in a live demo using the editor. We can't evaluate your script without knowing what it's running against.

Comment: 1. Check that the `DOMContentLoaded` event is truly being fired with a `console.log` 2. Check that the CSS class names `product-price` and `sqs-money-native` are still being used the same as before. 3. Make sure `price.textContent` or `price.innerText` is the decimal number only, and doesn't include a '$'.